# "missing parameter type" in groupBy

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scala-2.10

I'm a scala newbie that's having a hard time with what should be a simple line of code. I do a .groupBy operation and close over "it", but the compiler complains about a "missing parameter type", and I have no idea how to fix it. Here's the exact code (it's on a different network so I have to retype - excuse any typos):

```
val rddSAInCache: RDD[Map[String, Any]] = getCache(SAInCacheExported, rddconfig)
  .filter(it => it.path(EventType).getOrElse(NONE) == "SAInCache")
  .map(it => 
    Map(
      ("SAInCache" -> it.path(Time).getOrElse(NONE)), 
      (RequestID -> it.path(RequestID).getOrElse(NONE))
    )
  )
  .groupBy(it => it.path(RequestID.getOrElse(NONE))
```

The compiler is able to infer that "it" is a Map[String, Any] in both the filter and the map, but not the groupBy. Why??

Comment: The `groupBy` is after the `map`, so `it` is then a `Map`, which doesn't have a `.path` method. So maybe it's a real error, and the compiler is just getting confused trying to infer a type for code that can't be right?

Comment: We augmented Map to have a path method. That's not the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More of a suggestion than an answer:

Try splitting up the chained invocation:

```
val foo = rdd map f
val bar = foo groupBy g
```

Get the type of foo in the REPL.

You're asking it to solve the result type of the map, which is a Map, together with the groupBy, which is heavily overloaded and carries implicits.

Without knowing much about the API, it wouldn't surprise me if a type param is not inferrable.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, splitting up the chain. Thanks!